# Папка поддомен

Tags: .htaccess, php

Доброго времени суток! Как настроение ? :) 
Задался себе вопросом, как сделать под-домен (subdomain) через htaccess, так как в хостинге разрешено создать только 3 поддоменов, поэтому решил сделать еще и через htaccess, есть к примеру папка **partner**  путь: mysite.com/partner, а нужно сделать так: partner.mysite.com, помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: дак, вбил в поиск там ничего нету..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вопрос раз 10 наверное обсуждался на этом форуме, Максудджан :)

[Вот в поиске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search/?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD+htaccess&t=question)

Comment: Те коды вообще работают по другому, нужно сделать чтобы именно папки работали как поддомен..